# File uploaded in website root directory through post request

Tags: security, iis, google-search-console

Somebody uploaded some `deconfig.asp` file in my website root directory. I don't know how? When I checked the file owner, it was showing as IUSER iis user because my websites are running in IIS server 7.5. After uploading `deconfig.asp` file he just uploaded Google verification HTML file for verifying domain from Google webmaster tool. I am not able to find out how he was able to upload the file in website root directory without any login.

**How did he upload the files in the server?**

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: How he uploaded the files in the server?

Comment: The amount of possibilities are endless. If you want to know the real reason you would need help from a forensic professional. You probably have some vulnerabilitie in your code (check for https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) or some weak configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility could be HeartBleed, but as Jhuliano said. It could be endless.
Which hosting server are you using? Is your Cpanel udated with latest code

Comment: We own virtual server in Rackspace